# WCF REST Basic Authentication - not able to set authorization header

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, wcf-rest

I have created a WCF REST service and I am trying to do custom authentication (as it should work on http and https).

I am using custome service authorization manager to check and validate authorization header.

When I call the service using Fiddler and pass Authorization header with request, I am receiving it correctly in the service authorization manager.

But when I am setting credentials on WCFChannelFactory, I am not receiving Authorization header in the service. I expect that authorization header should be created by WCFChannelFactory and passed with request.

Client code is as below:

```
WebChannelFactory<IDataService> factory = new WebChannelFactory<IDataService>("DataServiceClient1");
factory.Credentials.UserName.UserName = "user1";
factory.Credentials.UserName.Password = "password123";
var client = factory.CreateChannel();
var data = client.GetData1("Microsoft");
Console.WriteLine("Get response : {0}", data);
```

Client Service Configuration is as below:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost.fiddler:50179/DataService.svc"
                binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="auth"
                contract="RESTWebServiceSpike.IDataService"
                behaviorConfiguration="web"
                name="DataServiceClient1">
      </endpoint>
    </client>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="web">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="auth">
          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

My service Configuration is as below:

```
<services>
  <service name="RESTWebServiceSpike.DataService" behaviorConfiguration="DataServiceBehaviour">
    <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding"
              contract="RESTWebServiceSpike.IDataService" behaviorConfiguration="web">
    </endpoint>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="DataServiceBehaviour">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" httpHelpPageEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceAuthorization serviceAuthorizationManagerType="RESTWebServiceImpl.AuthorizationManager, RESTWebServiceImpl" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="web">
      <webHttp/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

I am using custome service authorization manager to check and validate authorization header.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is late but I ran across this post so decided to fill this in, in case I ever need to remember this again. This worked for me:

1. Create the Message Inspector:

   ```
   Public Class AuthenticationHeader
     Implements IClientMessageInspector

   Private itsUser As String
   Private itsPass As String

   Public Sub New(ByVal user As String, ByVal pass As String)
       itsUser = user
       itsPass = pass
   End Sub

   Public Sub AfterReceiveReply(ByRef reply As Message, correlationState As Object) Implements IClientMessageInspector.AfterReceiveReply
       Console.WriteLine("Received the following reply: '{0}'", reply.ToString())
   End Sub

   Public Function BeforeSendRequest(ByRef request As Message, channel As IClientChannel) As Object Implements IClientMessageInspector.BeforeSendRequest
       Dim hrmp As HttpRequestMessageProperty = request.Properties("httpRequest")
       Dim encoded As String = System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes(itsUser + ":" + itsPass))
       hrmp.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded)
       Return request
     End Function
   End Class
   ```
2. Write the Behavior:

   ```
   Public Class AuthenticationHeaderBehavior
   Implements IEndpointBehavior

   Private ReadOnly itsUser As String
   Private ReadOnly itsPass As String

   Public Sub New(ByVal user As String, ByVal pass As String)
       MyBase.New()
       itsUser = user
       itsPass = pass
   End Sub

   Public Sub AddBindingParameters(endpoint As ServiceEndpoint, bindingParameters As BindingParameterCollection) Implements IEndpointBehavior.AddBindingParameters
   End Sub

   Public Sub ApplyClientBehavior(endpoint As ServiceEndpoint, clientRuntime As ClientRuntime) Implements IEndpointBehavior.ApplyClientBehavior
       clientRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(New AuthenticationHeader(itsUser, itsPass))
   End Sub

   Public Sub ApplyDispatchBehavior(endpoint As ServiceEndpoint, endpointDispatcher As EndpointDispatcher) Implements IEndpointBehavior.ApplyDispatchBehavior
   End Sub

   Public Sub Validate(endpoint As ServiceEndpoint) Implements IEndpointBehavior.Validate
   End Sub
   End Class
   ```
3. Add it to your endpoint:

   ```
     Dim binding As New WebHttpBinding(WebHttpSecurityMode.Transport)
     binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.None

     ChlFactory = New WebChannelFactory(Of IMyServiceContract)(binding, New Uri(url))
     ChlFactory.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(New WebHttpBehavior())
     ChlFactory.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(New AuthenticationHeaderBehavior(user, pass))
     Channel = ChlFactory.CreateChannel()
   ```

Answer (score 0):

For posterity, here is the solution I found to this problem:

First, take out your `<service></service>` tags in your client.

Then, you need to wrap your call to your service in an OperationContextScope, inside which you'll add the header.  For example:

```
using (new OperationContextScope((IClientChannel)client))
{
   HttpRequestMessageProperty requestProperty = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();
   string credentials = string.Format("{0}:{1}", _username, _password);
   requestProperty.Headers["Authorization"] = string.Format("Basic {0}", Convert.ToBase64String(UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(credentials)));
   OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name] = requestProperty;
   data = client.GetData1();
}
```

Here is an MSDN point of reference:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/drnick/archive/2008/07/08/adding-headers-to-a-call-http-version.aspx